# Check and Delete specific file in a folder and subfolders

Tags: search, vbscript, directory, delete-file, subdirectory

I was trying to write a code to check for a specific file if it is existing in a folder and subfolder in  any subfolder \DESKTOP in c:\users*.* (= all users directories). And if the file is existing in any folder the script will delete the file.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, FSO, DesktopPath
Dim objShortcutFile, objDesktopFolder, objDesktopSubFolder, Folder, strSysDrive

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

strSysDrive = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")

Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strSysDrive & "\Users")
msgbox Folder & "\sample1.lnk"
    For Each objDesktopFolder in Folder.SubFolders

        If FSO.FileExists(Folder & "\sample1.lnk") Then

            FSO.DeleteFile Folder & "\sample1.lnk"
            msgbox "success"

        Else

            msgbox "not existing"

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: The script does not do its job unless I copied the file in "C:\users". I need some sample on how to do that, I was thinking if I could use wmi to search through in any subfolder \DESKTOP in c:\users*.* (= all users directories).

Comment: Use `objDesktopFolder.Path & "\sample1.lnk"`  instead of  `Folder & "\sample1.lnk"` within the `For Each objDesktopFolder .. Next` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Folder` is the `C:\Users` folder object; `objDesktopFolder` is the folder object for each folder directly in `C:\Users`, e.g. C:\Users\user1 - not further levels of subfolders e.g. C:\Users\user1\Desktop (so it's a misleading name as it is not the desktop folder).

If you only want to look directly on the desktop, then just change this line (and any other line that uses that path):
`If FSO.FileExists(Folder & "\sample1.lnk") Then`

to:
`If FSO.FileExists(FSO.BuildPath(objDesktopFolder.Path, "Desktop\sample1.lnk")) Then`

If you also want to look through each folder that may exist on the desktop, then you'll have to perform the same sort of logic, e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, FSO, DesktopPath
Dim objShortcutFile, objDesktopFolder, objDesktopSubFolder, Folder, strSysDrive
Dim filepath, userfolder, desktop, subfolder, filename

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

strSysDrive = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")

Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strSysDrive & "\Users")
msgbox Folder & "\sample1.lnk"
filename = "sample1.lnk"
For Each userfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    desktop = FSO.BuildPath(userfolder.Path, "Desktop")
    filepath = FSO.BuildPath(desktop, filename)
    If FSO.FolderExists(desktop) Then
        ' Delete file on desktop
        If FSO.FileExists(filepath) Then
            FSO.DeleteFile filepath, True
            MsgBox "Success: deleted " & filepath
        Else
            MsgBox filepath & " doesn't exist"
        End If
        ' Check folders on desktop
        For Each subfolder In FSO.GetFolder(desktop).SubFolders
            filepath = FSO.BuildPath(subfolder.Path, filename)
            If FSO.FileExists(filepath) Then
                FSO.DeleteFile filepath, True
                MsgBox "Success: deleted " & filepath
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

That will only look for the file in folders directly on the desktop (as well as the file on the desktop, of course). If you want to look through further levels of subfolders then it's really best to create a separate sub that uses recursion to go through all levels of subfolders.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I'll try to create a sub that will look through further levels of subfolders.